# How to change header of a jsonwebtoken in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, jwt

I need a token to authenticate to a server, I am using `jsonwebtoken` , but it will only work if the header of the token is

```
{
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

and not

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

and `jsonwebtoken` default header is the second one, I tried to set the header in with option as explained here `https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken`, but there is no example so maybe I am doing it wrong, but `noTimestamp` option is working so...
There is this line in doc "The header can be customized via the options.header object." , i think that the point I don't get.

```
jwt.sign(payload,
      pvtKey,
      { algorithm: 'RS256', noTimestamp : true, header: {"alg": "RS256"} }, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).send("Error1: "+ err);
        }
        console.log("Created token: " + token);
      });
```

but it just doesn't change anything so if someone know how to set headers?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why does it not work with the `typ` header present? What problem does it cause?

Comment: It answer me that the token is invalid, the server is waiting for this header specifically, so i think they just compare the base64 header to what they are waiting for... I just builded a token step by step with `Buffer` and `crypto` so i get the header i want and it works, but i still want to know how to set header, since we are supposed to be able to do it by the doc

Comment: Really strange behavior on server side. You might have to go with your custom solution then.

Comment: @BobTheDuckLing I get the same issue, can you post your custom token creator code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `jwt.sign()` creates a default header like this:

```
{
  "alg": <algorithm>,
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

If a `header` parameter is present, a header will be created that contains additional key/value pairs according to the parameter. If the parameter contains a different value for `typ` or `alg`, the value from the parameter will be taken. And, as mentioned in the answer by Atul, if you set the value to `undefined`, you can also get rid of the standard header.
In the following example, I remove the `typ` key by setting it `undefined` and add an extra key `x`:

```
jwt.sign(payload, pvtKey,
    { algorithm: 'RS256', noTimestamp : true, header: {"typ": undefined, "x":"y"} })
```

The result is this header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x": "y"
}
```

Conclusion: it works, you can customize your header and also remove standard values (as pointed out by Atul in their answer)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove a default value from the header
you could also just set undefined

for example:

```
jwt.sign({ "hello": "world" }, key, { algorithm: "none", header: { typ: undefined } })
```

produces a jwt which has

payload:

```
{
  "hello": "world",
  "iat": 1627481195
}
```

and signature

```
{
  "alg": "none"
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution.  Adding "header: { typ: undefined }" removes the typ line from the generated token completely, and it still gets the other normal header fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
var h  = {"alg":"PS256", "typ":"unknown", "kid":"5FZT6gTLM5wEoSGn3eW0Q8zCPsQ"};
var i  = 'ClientId';   
var s  = 'ClientId';   
var a  = 'bla';
var signOptions = {
 issuer:  i,
 header:  h,
 subject:  s,
 audience:  a,
 expiresIn:  "1h"
};

var token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKEY, signOptions);
```

results in this header:

```
{
  "alg": "PS256",
  "typ": "unknown",
  "kid": "5FZT6gTLM5wEoSGn3eW0Q8zCPsQ"
}
```

Comment: you say, my answer is wrong. So, which (part of the) question did I answer wrong. And where does your answer give the (hopefully) right answer?

Comment: You can change the alg. Look at the example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please read the question and my answer again. 1. the OP did not ask about the alg header. 2. I didn't say that it can't be changed. I even said that you can overwrite it. 3. the question was how to remove the typ header, to which I replied.  So pls. remove your unfounded statement about my answer. You whole answer, which is basically a code only answer, doesn't add anything new.